# WebService to import entire table in android

Tags: c#, android, database, web-services, sql-server-2008

I have created a web service in C#  and wrote the getdata() function successfully that fetches a table from my database(on SQL Server 2008).I am not getting to call it from my android app. can someone share the example code. I need to sync the database and save data to my local android database. here's my getdata function.

```
[WebMethod]
public DataSet getData()
{
    SqlConnection conn;
    conn = ConnectionManager.GetConnection();
    conn.Open();

    string sqlQuery = "Select * From dbo.StudentContact";


    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    conn.Close();
    return ds;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read the following : [Call .Net webservice from android](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/304302/Calling-Asp-Net-Webservice-ASMX-From-an-Android-Ap) When you have called the webservice you can insert the values into your database on the device(All of the records that you have selected).

Comment: And what would we use within Android to hold a dataset from a c# web service?